# Hair loss in a nuclear submarine?

Tags: radiation

Biologically, how prevalent is hair loss on a nuclear submarine? How can prolonged exposure to radiation levels typically present on a nuclear sub affect a person, say over a year or even more?

Comment: http://nnsa.energy.gov/sites/default/files/nnsa/02-12-multiplefiles/NT-11-2%20FINAL.pdf

Comment: @canadianer Actually that is one of the links that I have mentioned in the answer I put up.

Comment: I did check your post to see if you had included it but apparently I missed it!

Comment: Nice question but wonder if better served In Physics stack?

Comment: The question is not clear. Can you improve it by providing more context and writing out what you are asking? Specifically, are you talking about nuclear submarines?

Comment: I knew a man in one of my chemistry classes who served on a nuclear submarine and worked with the reactor. He not only still had a full head of hair but told me that his radiation exposure tag picked up more radiation in a day on the beach than in 6 months next to the reactor. Obviously it's an anecdote, but I generally think people are too afraid of radiation.

Comment: Just read the pdf @canadianer linked, and it says average exposure per person per year is 0.022REM, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roentgen_equivalent_man#Health_effects) says people should be exposed to less than 100mREM per year, which is about 5 times more than what the naval personnel are exposed too. I may have missed something, I only spent 90 seconds to find these numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If the question is related to exposure to radiation in a **Nuclear** submarine then the answer is valid for radiation exposure irrespective of the place.

As you are aware there are many effects of radiation. Some of them are.

> - Nausea and vomiting
> - Diarrhea
> - Skin burns (skin reddening)
> - Weakness
> - Lethargy and fatigue
> - Loss of appetite (anorexia)
> - Fainting
> - Dehydration
> - Inflammation of tissues (swelling, redness or tenderness)
> - Hemorrhages under the skin
> - Bleeding from your nose, gums or mouth
> - Anemia
> - Hair loss (usually from just the scalp)
> - Decrease in platelets ([reference](http://www.naturalnews.com/032087_radiation_sickness_symptoms.html#))

Of course there is no safe quantity of radiation that has been quantified ([reference](http://yosemite.epa.gov/R10/CLEANUP.NSF/webpage/how+does+radiation+affect+human+health?OpenDocument)) and there are personal anecdotes by submarine officers about first hand problems they faced due to radiation ([reference](http://aquilinefocus.blogspot.in/2006/09/three-submarine-radiation-stories.html)). However, since this is a career you chose, you can be happy that the amount of radiation that you would be exposed to has decreased over the years ([reference](http://nnsa.energy.gov/sites/default/files/nnsa/02-12-multiplefiles/NT-11-2%20FINAL.pdf)). Since you are interested in the biological aspect of what happens in your body due to radiation, I quote

> When cells -- and what lies within them -- get exposed to radiation,
>   components of DNA and critical proteins within the cell get all jazzed
>   up (ionized), meaning that the electrons with our atoms get kicked
>   out, causing the DNA strands to break and the proteins to cramp up
>   (denature).
>
> Ionizing Radiation:
>
> - Leads to the production of free radicals
> - Breaks critical chemical bonds
> - Leads to changes in cellular structure within irradiated cells
> - Damages vital molecules, such as DNA, RNA, and other regulatory
>     proteins
>
> Because our cells are mostly water, this ionizing radiation breaking
>   H$_2$0 down is harmful to free radicals (H$^+$ and OH$^-$). While cells are
>   damaged by free radicals all the time, they normally repair
>   themselves, keeping the body healthy. However, high doses of radiation
>   can damage the cell's ability to repair itself, and then all hell
>   breaks loose.
>
> This shakes things up all over the body.
>
> Let's do a head-to-toe walk-through to investigate how high doses of
>   radiation can damage the human body.
>
> **BRAIN:** Nerve cells (neurons) and brain blood vessels can die, leading to seizures.
>
> **EYES:** Radiation exposure increases the risk of cataracts.
>
> **THYROID:** When a nuclear reactor malfunctions, radioactive iodine (I-131) can be released into the atmosphere (this is one of the
>   particles that hangs out in a "radioactive plume"). The thyroid is
>   very sensitive to the effects of I-131 (in fact, I-131's affinity for
>   the thyroid is used therapeutically to specifically attract radiation
>   to the thyroid in order to treat thyroid cancer and overactive
>   thyroid). When a healthy thyroid is exposed to I-131, it can lead to
>   decreased thyroid function and, over time, thyroid cancer.
>
> **LUNGS:** When you breathe in invisible nuclear fallout particles, it can lead to lung cancer down the road.
>
> **HEART:** High doses of radiation can damage the cells in the blood vessels that feed the heart, reducing cardiac function.
>
> **GI TRACT:** Sensitive cells in the intestinal lining can be damaged, leading to nausea, bloody vomiting, and bloody diarrhea.
>
> **REPRODUCTIVE ORGANS:** Rapidly dividing cells (eggs and sperm) in the ovaries and testes can die, leading to sterility.
>
> **SKIN:** Rapidly dividing skin cells can be damaged, leading to skin lesions and burn.
>
> **LYMPHATIC SYSTEM:** Rapidly dividing lymphatic cells die and damaged bone marrow may have trouble replenishing these immune-boosting cells,
>   increasing the risk of infection ([reference](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/owning-pink/201103/radiation-101-how-does-nuclear-radiation-affect-the-body)).

Many jobs have occupational diseases connected with it so I would say don't worry about it too much, enjoy your job and keep your fingers off the firing mechanism.

Comment: Nice answer. While the effects of a given are arguably kinda unknown, it would still be interesting to have some measurements (in Bequerel/Curries, in Greys or even more useful in Sievert/rems) or radioactivity in submarine.

Comment: @Remi.b Don't recall finding any but could exist.